# I need to get a random password generator to work

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans

Im trying to get this random password generator to work for an assignment.

```
    public String[] setPassword(){
        String upper= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String lower= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String num= "0123456789";
        String specialChar= "!@#%";
        String combination= upper + lower+ num + specialChar;
        int len=6;
        String[] password= new String[len];
        Random r= new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
            password [i]=combination(r.nextInt(combination.length()));
        }
        return password;
```

when i run the code the password comes back as null. I'm relatively new to coding so im not really sure how to debug it any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `String[] password= new String[len];` to `char[] password= new char[len];`. Then you can use `password [i]=combination.charAt(r.nextInt(combination.length()));`. Also your method should probably be declared as `public char[] generatePassword(){`

Comment: sorry im new to stack overflow and coding in general I changed the above the password still returns as null its part of a bigger class is there a way for me to post the entire thing. thank you for the help

Comment: please replace `lower = "abcd..."` with `lower = upper.toLowerCase()`

Comment: ive fixed the null error because i had password declared as a string earlier in the class fixed the errors and now it just comes back blank

Comment: `when i run the code the password comes back as null`. The code can't be compiled. Post the latest

Comment: um i copy and pasted the answer i got into my code but im not sure what ThreadLocalRandom is or how to fix the error :/

Comment: Security warning: do not use `new Random()` for a password. It’s way too easy to predict the numbers it produces and reconstruct your password. You may look into `SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic advice; simplify your code as much as possible. It appears you are generating a password, which should probably be a `String`. So return a `String`. The method doesn't use any class state, so it should be `static` (and it *generates* a password, so name it something like that). Use a `StringBuilder`. Use the `current()` `ThreadLocalRandom`. Something like,

```
public static String generatePassword() {
    String upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String num = "0123456789";
    String specialChar = "!@#%";
    String combination = upper + upper.toLowerCase() + num + specialChar;
    int len = 6;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(combination.charAt(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                        combination.length()
                )
        ));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which I ran like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(generatePassword());
}
```

Comment: I would say that it's a bit early to talk about optimizing with StringBuilders, but the solution is correct

Comment: yeah you lost me at StringBuilders but i will try this

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( what is threadlocalrandom?

Comment: [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

Comment: Using a more secure pseudorandom number generator is far more important than optimization.